# Eta expansion - name origin

Tags: functional-programming

Just wondering where the name come from, eta?

The only two things I know about eta are:

- estimated time of arrival
- seventh letter of Greek alphabet

Comment: Most likely from the same source as *alpha renaming* and *beta reduction*, I guess. Waiting to see answers.

Comment: 100% sure it is not 'estimated time of arrival'

Comment: @leppie yeah it's probably not ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that that the rules were simply taken from start of the Greek alphabet:

- α - [variable renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_Conversion)
- β - [beta reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Beta_reduction_.28capture_avoiding.29)
- γ - (I haven't seen any gamma rule, if you have, please let me know)
- δ - Church's delta rule (see a very short notice in [Barendregt, H. P. The Lambda Calculus: Its Syntax and Semantics.](http://mathgate.info/cebrown/notes/barendregt.php)):

> `δ MN = T` if `M=N` and `δ MN = F` if `M` is not `N` for all closed nf's `M` and `N`
>
> ε - (I haven't seen any epsilon rule)
>
> ζ - if `Ux=Vx` and `x` doesn't occur in `UV` then `U=V`
>
> η - the [eta-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Eta_reduction)
>
> A further interesting source of information could be [History of Lambda-calculus and
>   Combinatory Logic](http://maths.swan.ac.uk/staff/jrh/papers/JRHHislamWeb.pdf) by F.Cardone and J.R.Hindley, it's likely that there were some rules that have been abandoned long time ago.